What is Life in a Deterministic Universe?
In a deterministic universe, where every event is a result of preceding causes, the distinctions we make between living and non-living entities might be an illusion. Our perceptions—colors, sounds, and even the idea of life itself—are simply the outcomes of chemical and physical events. These patterns are not inherently different from other events in the universe; they are merely interpreted by our brains in specific ways due to our biological programming.
Consequently, questioning whether there is life on other planets becomes less about identifying entities that are 'alive' or 'dead' and more about understanding different modes of perception. What we categorize as life could be vastly different elsewhere in the universe, with other organisms possibly perceiving us as nothing more than sequences of chemical reactions.
The common assumption that extraterrestrial life must be similar to us in interaction and perception might be narrow-minded. Given the deterministic nature of the universe, the likelihood of encountering life forms that interact with their environments as we do is slim.
Given this premise, how should we define 'life' in a deterministic universe?

Growing, reproducing, taking energy and materials from the environment in a manner that reduces entropy in the living thing... The usual stuff, I think? I don't see how it affects anything that the universe is deterministic. If it wasn't, life probably wouldn't arise at all.

In the first part, you are describing life as we understand it, but the original post challenges our limited understanding of life. Regarding the second part: that is merely an assumption

So we would start with the definition we have and then... what? Do you have some thoughts on what to add or modify?

The post is literally about finding a new definition because what we call ‘life’ is only a limited interpretation of it. The post is very explicit about this, what part of the post was not clear to you that you are asking this question?

The whole question is completely pointless. There can be no kind of life by any definition in a deterministic system.

@Scott Rowe I have always had a question: why is reproduction a necessary condition for defining life? Is it not enough to define life as naturally occurring organic matter that can obtain energy and substances from the environment to reduce entropy within living organisms?

@Perttiruismaki. Is there something about determinism which would prevent abiogenisis, necessarily?

@PerttiRuismäki your claim is incorrect. Determinism doesn’t rule out life, it simply means that life follows predictable rules. Claiming that life cannot exist in a deterministic system is fundamentally wrong.

@Futilitarian There is no evolution in determinism,  nothing changes, nothing new emerges, entropy and complexity do not increase. A deterministic system is a clockwork mechanism, whose every move is determined completely by the previous move.

@DavitJanashia Determinism is much more than just following rules. In determinism every event is completely determined by the previous event. There is no possibility for anything even remotely resembling life in a clockwork mechanism.

@PerttiRuismäki. Determinism doesn't necessitate clockwork, which is cyclical.

@Futilitarian Cyclicality is irrelevant in this metaphor.

@PerttiRuismäki your statement is fundamentally wrong. Deterministic systems can evolve in predictable ways.

@DavitJanashia I'm afraid it's you who is wrong this time. Look up the definition of determinism and try to understand what it means.

@MikeSong I suppose we could simplify it to stuff that grows by reducing entropy within itself. Does that let anything in that doesn't seem like 'life'? (I keep hearing Spock say, "Pure energy." ha ha)

@ScottRowe cold water and hot air for a start. Anyway, organisms (and any other system that grows by adding more of the same chemical stuff at the same temperature) grow while increasing internal entropy.

"Ugly! Ugly bags of mostly water!"

You say:

In a deterministic universe, where every event is a result of
preceding causes, the distinctions we make between living and
non-living entities might be an illusion.

Well, if that's the case, then why not in a non-deterministic universe too?
You say:

Our perceptions—colors, sounds, and even the idea of life itself—are
simply the outcomes of chemical and physical events. These patterns are not inherently different from other events in the universe; they are merely interpreted by our brains in specific ways due to our biological programming.

Well, here you are suggesting that perceptions are defined by the outcomes of physical events that ... are common (via determinism) throughout the universe. So, it must follow that our biological programming is based on these patterns. From this, it follows that all life, throughout the universe, should have taken the same approach in evolving. And if not, how is this related to determinism?
So, what you then say:

Given the deterministic nature of the universe, the likelihood of
encountering life forms that interact with their environments as we do
is slim.

at leat to me, is a contradiction.

When we say deterministic universe - in physics - we mean that the state of the universe at any given time and the basic laws of physics fully determine the universe's backward history and forward evolution.


I am talking about a deterministic universe because we live in one. But who said it would not be the same in a non-deterministic universe? The post doesn’t suggest this anywhere.



Your logical conclusions are incorrect. Why should it follow the same patterns as us to be considered life? The post discusses exactly this issue, by the way.


Also, this relates to life because in a deterministic universe, there is no real free will. Therefore, life is simply a series of chemical and physical reactions. This idea shifts our usual understanding of what life means

@Davit Janashia, determinism and free will are not mutually exclusive. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism

Defining life does not require one to decide between common ontological commitments. Dualists, monists, naturalists, supernaturalists, and so on all agree that there exist sequences of processes with various characteristics. Therefore defining life to have as one of its meanings a particular kind of sequence of processes requires no selection between these ontological commitments.
Definitions are arbitrary, but science fiction authors and speculative exobiologists tend towards some implicit approximation of:
natural life

a system of processes which is: self-duplicating, dissipative, subject to occasional heritable copy errors which can increase the size or complexity of the self-duplicating part of the system, and acted on thereby by selection pressures.
the category whose members are such systems


Above I tried to answer the spirit of the question. As for the literal question, it's a category error.

Given this premise, how should we define 'life' in a deterministic
universe?

If we start with the premise that everything, including our thoughts and how they make us feel, is determined, reasoning from premises is meaningless and should is a nonsense concept. To care about any conclusions we might make about deterministic universes, we have to start with the assumption that we don't live in one.

You’re misunderstanding a key point. Predetermination doesn’t invalidate reasoning—it’s essential for making sense of our circumstances and guiding our decisions. Even if everything is predetermined, we don’t have control over all the information in the universe. With limited information, we need to reason to survive

Kant's 3rd antinomy offers two contradictory proofs regarding whether the world is deterministic or not.
I.e. Arguing for freedom (spontaneity): With an infinite causal chain, there's no identifiable first cause that ultimately triggers events. But we know events happen so there must be a first event. (An infinite chain with no starting point does not provide a clear reason for anything happening.)
Vs. With freedom (spontaneity) any event could just happen, but that contradicts the principle of sufficient reason, so there is no freedom.
Accordingly the OP's premise of a deterministic universe is not founded on reason and arbitrarily confines the possible definitions of life.

The question of whether the Universe is fully deterministic is irrelevant to the question of how we define life. Yes, it is possible that our conception of life might be limited, in the sense that there could be entities in other parts of the Universe that might cause us to revise or extend our definition of life were we to encounter them, but that could be the case whether the Universe is deterministic or not, and unless or until that happens, our current definition remains fit for purpose.

The nature of the universe, whether deterministic or not, strongly influences our understanding of life. For instance, take free will: in a deterministic universe, true free will doesn’t exist. This is crucial because the presence or absence of free will determines how independent a life form is from external forces, affecting our perception of autonomy.

But it has nothing to do with our definition of life! Life is life regardless of whether it possesses free will!

The premise of your question is faulty:
The idea that the universe could be deterministic came of age with the huge success of Newtonian mechanics. However, Aristotle noted that some philosophers said that chance could be a cause and this was explicitly included in ancient Greek atomism with their notion of the swere or climamen. This notion of an inherently indeterministic universe came to prominence with the discovery of QM.
The notion of consciousness is, despite much effort, still remains a mystery and isn't generally taken to be mechanistic in its essentials. Conciousness then is still the main aporia in how we think about the universe mechanically in the most broadest fashion.

Your argument is flawed. Quantum indeterminacy and the mysteries of consciousness aren’t solid grounds to dismiss determinism. Our current understanding of quantum mechanics, including key concepts like photons, is incomplete. Therefore, it’s premature to reject determinism when exploring questions about the nature of life

@Davit Janashia: At any time our understanding will be incomplete. Nevertheless, we judge on what we know now and not on some speculative notion of what the future may bring.

Quantum mechanics is underdeveloped, and relying on it to dispute determinism is premature. Our understanding in this area is not just incomplete; it’s insufficient to overturn long-standing theories like determinism

It’s important to base such significant arguments on well-established facts rather than partial understandings

@Davit Janashia: QM is actually highly developed - and no-one has thought up a theory beyond it. You're indulging in speculativism.

Before posting such claims, it’s crucial to better inform yourself about the current state and ongoing advancements in the field. The assertion that quantum mechanics is "highly developed" is far from truth. It still struggles with major issues like integrating with general relativity and solving problems like quantum decoherence and the measurement problem. The active exploration in fields like quantum gravity and string theory further shows that quantum mechanics is far from complete.

@Davit Janashia: All you're saying is that quantum physics is an ongoing project. That is not under dispute. Nevertheless all current investigations takes its ontological indeterminancy onboard. Whereas you are merely asserting determinism without takimg account of what our latest theories actually say.

Quantum indeterminacy doesn’t necessarily mean that deterministic principles can’t apply at the quantum level. It may simply indicate that we don’t yet fully understand the underlying mechanisms. The observed randomness in quantum mechanics could be a reflection of our current limitations in knowledge, rather than proof of an inherently indeterministic universe. it’s premature to dismiss the possibility of determinism in quantum theory until we have a more complete understanding of these phenomena.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In a deterministic universe there can be no life. For the same reason there can be no deterministic universes.
For a universe (and life within) to exist, it must either:

Evolve, or
Be created by a divine entity.

Both alternatives are excluded from determinism. A deterministic system does not evolve, its complexity and entropy remain constant. Divine creation requires free will, which is not present in deterministic conditions.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
